# Why does Angular $resource return a Resource object instead of the class object?

Tags: angularjs, coffeescript

Using CoffeeScript, Angular and $resource, I've created the following factory:

```coffee
angular.module('myapp', ['ngResource']).factory 'MyObject', ['$resource', ($resource) ->
    MyObjectResource = $resource '/api/my_object/:id', {
      id: '@id'
    }, {
      update:
        method: 'PUT'
    }

    class MyObject extends MyObjectResource

      someMethod: ->
        dosomething
 ]
```

The problem is that when I load an object from my API, I get a `Resource`  object instead of a `MyObject` object, which is a problem, because I don't have access to my other methods.

Here is my code to get an object:

```coffee
result = MyObject.get({id: 1})
```

If I print `result`, I can see:

```
Resource {id: 1, details: 'somestuff'}
```

By contrast, I would expect to have:

```
MyObject {id: 1, details: 'somestuff'}
```

which would give me access to `someMethod` and all other methods that I've defined for this class.

Am I doing something wrong?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After having a quick look at the source code I see the following relationships:

1. There's a `Resource` function created inside the factory (which is the `$resource` provider) and is returned when `$resource` is called.

Resource has the following structure (let's imagine that we just want to have a high level view of what method it has but not what each method does)

```
function Resource(value) { ... }
Resource.prototype.toJSON = function () { ... }
Resource.prototype.bind = function () { ... }
```

2. I also see that the `$resource` function receives in the 3rd paramater additional actions (which are merged with some default actions) to be set on the `Resource` function, I see that you're sending an additional `update` method, so the object has the following structure

Merging `update` with the default actions:

```
{
  'get': {method: 'GET'},
  'save': {method: 'POST'},
  'query': {method: 'GET', isArray: true},
  'remove': {method: 'DELETE'},
  'delete': {method: 'DELETE'},
  // added by the user
  update: { method: 'PUT' }
}
```

`$resource` sets a method for each property of this hash on the `Resource` function and also on the prototype of `Resource` appending a `$` before the method name, i.e.

```
Resource.get = function () { ... }
Resource.save = function () { ... }
Resource.update = function () { ... }
...

Resource.prototype.$get = function () { ... }
Resource.prototype.$save = function () { ... }
Resource.prototype.$update = function () { ... }
...
```

Now returning to your code you're extending a new function `MyObject` from `MyObjectResource` where `MyObjectResource` is the result of calling `$resource` i.e. the `Resource` function seen above, coffeescript's `extend` will actually copy all the properties defined on `MyObjectResource` to `MyObject` and also make the hidden `[[Prototype]]` property of `MyObject.prototype` point to `MyObjectResource.prototype`:

```
MyObjectResource                
  prototype     ------->  MyObjectResource.prototype
                            $get
  get                       $save
  save                      toJSON
  ...                       ...
                             ^
                             |
MyObject                     |
  prototype     ------->  MyObject.prototype
  get (reference)           someMethod
  set (reference)
  ...
```

So that's why you can do `MyObject.get` because it has now a reference to `MyObjectResource.get`, i.e. `MyObject.get === MyObjectResource.get`

Here's the interesting part, calling `MyObject.get` will return an instance of `MyObjectResrouce` (this is actually harcoded but only happens when inside `MyObject.get` `this` is not an instance of `MyObjectResource` [Source](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/master/src/ngResource/resource.js#L556)), if we do `new MyObjectResource()` there's no way to access `someMethod` because that's actually defined in a "subclass".

However we can create an instance of `MyObject` and because of the links created by coffeescript's `extend` the instance has access to the same `get` through `MyObjectResource.prototype.$get`, so:

```
var instance = new MyObject()
instance.$get({id: 1});     // works because of the link created between the prototypes
instance.someMethod();      // also works
```

Comment: Awesome answer which totally makes sense. Thanks a lot Mauricio!